# HAProxy Keep-Alive - 1.5-dev21

Tags: http, keep-alive, haproxy

We are running HAProxy V1.5 as described above. I am trying to enable Keep-Alive and have noticed the response headers do not contain the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header.

Our haproxy.cfg contains the following defaults which I believe should enable keep alive:

```
    mode http
    timeout connect 15000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 30000ms
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    option http-keep-alive
```

I notice if I get rid of option http-keep-alive then the `Connection: Close` 
response header is being returned. Can anyone tell me is HAProxy not returning the `Keep-Alive` header as it's technically not requires in http 1.1 forward or is it that HAProxy simply isn't enabling Keep-Alive.

If it is the latter can anyone tell me why it wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 2):

From HAProxy's documentation:

> By default HAProxy operates in keep-alive mode with regards to
>   persistent connections: for each connection it processes each request
>   and response, and leaves the connection idle on both sides between the
>   end of a response and the start of a new request.

And from the wikipedia article about Keep-Alive:

> In HTTP 1.1, all connections are considered persistent unless declared
>   otherwise

So to answer clearly to your question: Haproxy doesn't send `Connection: Keep-Alive` since it is not required with `HTTP 1.1`, since all connections are considered persistent unless declared otherwise.

You would probably see a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header if you connected with an `HTTP 1.0` client.